# How to add shortcut keys like F1 or F2 or F3 F4 instead of enter for submitting form using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, forms, shortcut

How i can submit my form with keys F1, F2, F3 or F4 etc using javascript my form is submit using ajax and enter i don't want to submit it with enter.

Answer (score 0):

use sample :

```
$("body").keydown(function(e){
  //well so you need keep on mind that your browser use some keys 
  //to call some function, so we'll prevent this
  e.preventDefault();

  //now we caught the key code.
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  //your keyCode contains the key code, F1 to F12 
  //is among 112 and 123. Just it.
  console.log(keyCode);  

    //form submit
  if(keyCode >111 && keyCode<116){
    $("myForm").submit(); 
  } 
  
});
```

Comment: Notice, that both [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which) are deprecated.

Comment: $("body"). What about this?